# Pinhole Camera on Shabbos

Tags: shabbat, melacha-creative-work, writing-printing, pictures

I read somewhere that one of the reasons you can't take pictures on Shabbos is because of the melacha of Kotev/Writing.

Does this also apply to a [pinhole camera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinhole_camera) which does create a temporary image but not with ink or the sort?

Comment: What's a pinhole camera? Is it just making a shadow in a particular shape?

Comment: PC is about lack of lens not recording which is identical to a regular camera. Please clarify how you intend to use it on Shabbos.

Answer (score -2):

If there is no PHYSICAL change, it's ok. This Camera Obscura does not make any physical change, and it just letting the light pass in.

Comment: Source for this?

Comment: Change of what? Light passes and lands on what?